# How to use windows authenication while having an anonymous page

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have the following structure

login.aspx

reallysecure/homepage.aspx

I'm trying to allow anonymous access to login.aspx and windows authenication to reallysecure/homepage.aspx

My IIS auth is configured to only have anonymous enabled.

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<location path="reallysecure">
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <authentication>
      <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"></windowsAuthentication>
    </authentication>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

When I navigate to login.aspx everything works as intended.  However when I redirect to reallysecure/homepage.aspx i get the following error:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

81:         <authentication>
  82:           <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"></windowsAuthentication>
 83:         </authentication>
```

How do i setup the web.config and IIS to accomplish what i need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of authentication vs authorization. Windows authentication should be set at the root level, and should be used for the entire site. But at the root level, you'll specify that anonymous users are allowed, and in "reallysecure" specify that anonymous users are not allowed.

So, instead of the authentication section in the location, set up an authorization section:

```
<authorization>
<deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

(? == anonymous)

And, at the root level, it should be:

```
<authorization>
<allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

(* == all users, including anonymous)

Comment: Mike2500 - how do you post credentials to securelly entire the windows authorized section?

Comment: When you hit the root site, you'll get in, as it's anonymous. When you navigate to a part of the site where anonymous is denied, then you'll be prompted to enter credentials. (by prompted, I mean a standard windows credentials dialog)

Comment: m g I dont want to be prompted, the anony site is a login site where those credentials will be supplied i just want to pass them in so the user isnt prompted

Comment: I apologize, I misread your first post. The only page you want anonymous folks to go to is the login page? Then just deny anonymous at the root, they will automatically be redirected to the login page. But, since you have a login page, you're trying to use forms auth, not windows auth. If it's an internal app for folks already logged in, do you need the login.aspx page? Will integrated windows auth not work for you? If you want a custom form that uses AD, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx

Comment: m g - i dont want to to use forms auth

Comment: So why do you have login.aspx?

Comment: Perhaps we should back up. Instead of listing files and such, what behavior do you want, and are all users already logged into machines that are part of the domain?

Comment: m g no i want remote users to have a custom login box where they can supply their NT credentials and access sites that are set to windows authenication.  Remotely... and if you use forms auth you cant handle a lot of securite customization

Comment: Right, that's forms authentication, just using the AD provider. See the link I posted earlier. It's a walkthrough that shows how to set up a custom form that lets a user log in via their windows domain credentials. If you want more examples, just search for "asp.net ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider". Also see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alvar/archive/2009/02/03/using-asp-net-2-0-forms-authentication-with-active-directory-membership-provider.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: m g i have forms auth working.  However, i dont want forms auth, for a multiple reasons namly SQL connections are based on the app pool and using forms auth you have to use anony auth, i'm not kidding when i say i dont want forms auth

Comment: SQL connections? What SQL connections? Forms auth doesn't have to use the asp.net databases, it can use AD! But, Windows auth == no custom login form. Ok, one potential exception to that, have your proxy handle the auth, and provide a form from the proxy. But proxy possibilities aside, having a custom form==forms authentication.  (but again, forms authentication != asp.net user database. )

Comment: m g proxy handle it?  Do you have an example

Comment: Firewalls aren't my bailywick, but hopefully this will help: http://www.projectleadership.net/blogs_details.php?id=2625

Comment: m g does it create windows session or just auth windows

Comment: Ask a firewall admin for details, but it does authenticate the user, and enables the user to then connect to the server without having to log in again, and with the server set to use windows auth. This is often used for single sign on scenarios, where an external domain user needs to connect to different servers, but they don't want the user to be prompted each time they switch servers. Another write-up: http://demantprasad.blogspot.com/2012/12/securing-sharepoint-sites-with.html